# Python. FileNotFoundError

Tags: python

Совершаю запрос на открытие картинки расположенной на смартфоне подключённом к ПК по USB

```py
import os

os.startfile(r'POCO X3 Pro\Внутренний общий накопитель\DSC01968.JPG')
```

В ответ:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл: '\\POCO X3 Pro\\Внутренний общий накопитель\\DSC01968.JPG'
```

Картинка не битая. USB-порт целый - пробовал флэшку подключать, всё читается без проблем, но на флэшке и путь указывается по человечески 'D:\и поехали дальше...'
А тут в свойства картинки заходишь там путь такой: «Название компьютера\POCO X3 Pro\Внутренний общий накопитель», ну я копирую вставляю, добавляю естественно название картинки с типом .jpg и нифига не работает!
Помогите!!!

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку подключенный телефон не является как таковым диском, а читается системой при помощи `MTP`, то получить доступ к его содержимому обычными способами не получиться - нужно использовать `MTP`. В `python` для этого есть библиотека [pymtp](https://pypi.org/project/PyMTP/).
Однако стоит учитывать, что некоторые модели телефонов, например последние поколения Samsung, не получиться без проблем *прочитать* даже при помощи этой библиотеки. Собственно поэтому я пишу ответ без толкового примера применения этой библиотеки, а оставляю в качестве примера этот, простите за выражение, *огрызок* как отправную точку для вас.:

```
import pymtp
oMTP = pymtp.MTP()
oMTP.connect()
```

Comment: Cпасибо конечно, может я что-то сделал не так, но ничего не вышло. Python ещё больше отругал! Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\Project1\21_read-write-save files.py", line 2, in <module> import pymtp File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pymtp.py", line 41, in <module> libmtp = ctypes.CDLL(_module_path) File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ctypes__init_.py", line 364, in init if '/' in name or '\\' in name: TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Comment: Да, данный код не особо помогает, хоть и мультиплатформенный. У меня получается узнать информацию о девайсе, но вот приконнектиться - нет. Тем не менее, ОС (не суть, Linux или Windows) работает с mtp, а потому, думаю, надо копать в этом направлении.